# Can it hurt you to eat a worm in a strawberry

Tags: digestion, food-safety, fruits, filariasis

My grandson loves strawberries, but this morning he was eating his cereal and I had cut up strawberries to put in it. My eye sight is not the best, but I think that slice of berry must have been turned over and I just did not see the worm. He was close to his last bite when he saw this brown worm in his strawberry. Needless to say he said 'he is never eating strawberries again". Just wondering if he actually did eat some worms in the strawberries... will this hurt him? I ate the same berries yesterday as well.

Comment: Short version: Probably not.

Comment: Shorter version: Free protein.